# When will one be able to

Tags: translation, grammar, simplified-characters

How do you say "When will I be able to go to China?"

After trying to figure out and failed, I tried to translate the sentence from Korean to Chinese and came up with this :
"什么时候能去中国?"

Now, the questions are:

- Is that correct?
- Why is there no question marker (such as 吗) in the translation? I wonder when I should use 吗...
- When are we allowed to omit question marks?
- And why is it using 能? Shouldn't it be using 会? Since 会 is more related to future possibility.

Comment: The character 吗 occurs usually when the question is a "yes/no" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is correct, yet not precise, it is supposed to be

> 我什么时候能去中国？

Second and third, there is no question marker because "什么" already implied that this is a question, you would use "吗" when it is not obvious if the sentence is a question

> 我能去中国吗？

Last, "能" corresponds to "able" in original expression. You use "会" for possibility, like

> 他什么时候会去中国？

This means "when will he go to China?".

Comment: I see! Thank you soooooo much! You are a big help!

Comment: @Agnes You are absolutely welcome!

Comment: @Agnes If you think this answer resolved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the arrow on the left.

Comment: I have up voted it